# Is there a cleaner way to iterate through Mongo query results in Fantom?

Tags: mongodb, fantom

I'm writing a web app in [Fantom language](http://fantom.org) and using [afMongo](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afMongo/) to access a Mongo DB instance. Following the example in afMongo documentation I get the results of a query that I need to iterate through. In a simplified example, the iteration looks like this

```
    class MapListIterator {
      Void main(){
        [Str:Obj?][] listOfMaps := [,]
        listOfMaps.add(
          ["12345":[
             "id":12345,
             "code":"AU",
             "name":"Australia"
          ]])

        listOfMaps.each |Str:Obj? map| {
          echo(map.keys)
          keys := map.keys
          keys.each {
            echo(it)
            echo(((Str:Obj?)map[it])["code"])
            echo(((Str:Obj?)map[it])["name"])
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I ran this code in [Fantom online playground](http://fanzy.net) and it works Ok, but I wonder if it is a cleaner way to iterate through the results. I don't like the casting in my code above. Also, is there a better way to write the nested it-block, please?

**EDIT:**

Turns out that I was overcomplicating things. This is how the code looks after applying Steve's suggestions:

```
Str:Country mapOfCountries := [:]
mapOfCountries.ordered = true

listOfMaps := ([Str:Str?][]) collection.findAll
listOfMaps.each {
  c := it["code"]
  n := it["name"]
  mapOfCountries.add(c, Country { code = c ; name = n })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-cast the result and assign the map early on... which gives:

```java
listOfMappedMaps := ([Str:[Str:Obj?]][]) listOfMaps

listOfMappedMaps.each {
    map := it
    map.keys.each {
        echo(map[it]["code"])
        echo(map[it]["name"])
    }
}
```

The next step would be use [Morphia](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afMorphia/) which lets you use objects in place of maps.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how to access the external "it" within the nested "each". Also, the early cast works great. I still have to try the Morphia way.